# App submission phase for web site

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I've been implementing several Adaptive API calls for a PHP-powered web site. In [Going Live with Your Application](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/going-live-with-your-application) there're several mentions to "submitting your app for approval" as a mandatory step to get an Application ID and be allowed to use the production environment.

I know that web sites are allowed to use the API because some documents say it explictly but this guide seems to assume you're writing an app for a mobile device.

How does it work exactly when we are talking about a web site? Am I supposed to ZIP and upload the complete web site sources with assets and all, or is it enough to send the PHP class that handles the PayPal part?

<sub>1. *Yes, we've asked PayPal several days ago but never got an answer.

2. This is on-topic per the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq): «software tools commonly used by programmers [...]
practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession»*</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit an application you will be asked to provide the URL to your website and a test user/password if applicable, so the person reviewing your application could test the functionality if needed. You don't need to upload the actual PHP code.
Regarding "Yes, we've asked PayPal several days ago but never got an answer", how did you contact PayPal? Do you have a ticket #? I would like to follow up to see why you did not get an answer.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. PayPal was contacted by a co-worker, not sure of the details, but finally got a phone answer. He was told no review is required :-?

Comment: Some applications are auto approved depending on what APIs you need to use.